# How to initialize a TextField and get the text into TextFlow in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Controller:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller {
     @FXML TextFlow textFlow;
     @FXML TextField textField = new TextField();

    public void click(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.print(textField.getText());
        Text text = new Text("Text from textField");
        textFlow.getChildren().add(text);
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to be able to get the text from the textField and print it to textFlow. I'm new to Java and I've done some searches. How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Create ActionListener for some component and do:

```
String text = textField.getText();
```

and

```
textFlow.getChildren().addAll(text);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've added Text text = new Text(textField.getText());